# Combining cte with dates and table with dates between two dates

Tags: sql, date, t-sql, common-table-expression

I have a few pieces of code that give me things that I need, but I need some help for put them together.
I have:

```
create table #test ( job int, dateL date)
insert into #test values
(1, '2022-04-01'),
(2, '2022-04-02'),
(3, '2022-04-12'),
(4, '2022-04-27'),
(5, '2022-05-01')

declare
@startdate date = '2022-04-01',
@enddate date = '2022-04-30'
```

for that I  needed to see in which week of set period named job is appeared, but also I need to find the start date of every week. So I have cte that does that, and then code that finds jobs

```
;with cte as
(
  select @startDate StartDate
  union all
  select dateadd(ww, 1, StartDate)
  from cte
  where dateadd(ww, 1, StartDate)<=  @endDate
)



SELECT job,dateL,
(
  SELECT CASE 
    WHEN dateL BETWEEN @startdate AND  @enddate THEN DATEDIFF(wk, @startdate, dateL) 
    ELSE -1 
END
)
AS WeekNumber 
from #test
```

so cte shows every first day of the week:

```
StartDate
2022-04-01
2022-04-08
2022-04-15
2022-04-22
2022-04-29
```

and select shows

```
job dateL   weeknumber
1   2022-04-01  1
2   2022-04-02  1
3   2022-04-12  2
4   2022-04-27  4
5   2022-05-01  -1
```

How can I unite them, so there would be 4th column, that shows with week number, the start of that week?
Thanks!

Comment: Side note, I strongly suggest using a Tally rather than an rCTE for generating values like your dates; they are *significantly* more performant.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the side note, I didn't even know those are existed, I read about Tally right now, and all the examples oddly show the same syntaxes, just but Tally instead of cte... so like not  ;with cte as , but ;with Tally ...is it correct?

Comment: No, `WITH CTE` and `WITH Tally` are identical other than the name/alias of the CTE. You could just as easily have `WITH JimbleGangleSillyNamey`. It's about what you *do* in the CTE.

Comment: Yeah, as I figured...I found the info, thanks! I wont sure I will use it here, cause In the near future it could be more than one column(with end of week too)... But thank! New quickly working stuff are always fun to get to know of!

Comment: I don't see what having more columns has to do with not using a Tally...

Comment: Aside: From [Transact-SQL Syntax Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transact-sql-syntax-conventions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15): "`;` Transact-SQL statement terminator. Although the semicolon is not required for most statements in this version of SQL Server, it will be required in a future version." Break the `;with` habit now.